# Printing elements of a set in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

I want to print the elements of the set consecutively, so I wrote the following code:

```
s='dmfgd'
print(set(s))
```

However, this code shows the output as:

```
set(['m', 'd', 'g', 'f'])
```

but, I want output like:

```
set(['d','m','f','g'])
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `list(dict(zip(s,s)))` should solve your issue

Comment: Or: `print(sorted(set(s),key=s.index))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set is unordered. You can instead use a list of dict keys to emulate an ordered set if you're using Python 3.6+:

```
print(list(dict.fromkeys(s)))
```

This outputs:

```
['d', 'm', 'f', 'g']
```

Answer (score 1):

Python `set` is [unordered](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) collections of unique elements

Try:

```
s='dmfgd'

def removeDups(s):
    res = []
    for i in s:
        if i not in res:
            res.append(i)
    return res

print(removeDups(s))
```

**Output:**

```
['d', 'm', 'f', 'g']
```